# how to plot histogram of maximum values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, statistics

I have a dataframe with 3 columns `df=["a", "b", "value"]`. (Actually this is a snippet, the solution should be able to handle n variables, like "a", "b", "c", "d"...) In this case, the "value" column has been generated depending on the "a" and "b" value, doing something like:

```
        for a in range(1,10):
            for b in range (1,10):
                generate_value(a,b)
```

The resulting data is similar to:

```
  a b value
0 1 1 0.23
1 1 2 6.34
2 1 3 0.25
3 1 4 2.17
4 1 5 5.97
[...]
```

I want to know the statistical better combinations of "a" and "b" that gives me the bigger "value". So I want to draw some kind of histogram that shows me which values of "a" and "b" statistically generates bigger "value". I tried with something like:

```
fig = plot.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.hist(df["a"],bins=50, normed=True)
```

or:

```
 plot.plot(df["a"].values, df["value"].values, "o")
```

But the results are not good. I think that I should use some kind of histogram or gauss bell curve, but I'm not sure how to plot it.

So, how to plot the statistically better "a" and "b" to get maximum "value"?

***Note:*** the answer 1 is perfect for two variables a and b, but the problem is that the correct answer would need to work for multiple variables, a, b, c, d...

---

**Edit 1:** Please note that although I'm asking about two variables, the solution can't be to bound "a" to axis x and "b" to axis y, as there may be more variables. So if we have "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", the solution should be valid

**Edit 2:** Trying to explain it better: Lets take the following dataframe:

```
  a b c d value
0 1 6 9 7 0.23
1 5 2 3 5 11.34
2 6 7 8 4 0.25
3 1 4 9 3 2.17
4 1 5 9 1 4.97
5 6 6 4 7 25.9
6 3 5 5 2 10.37
7 1 5 1 2 7.87
8 2 5 3 3 8.12
9 1 5 2 1 2.97
10 7 5 4 9 5.97
11 3 5 2 3 9.92
[...]
```

The row 5 clearly is the winner, with a 25.9 value, so the supposedly better values of a,b,c,d are: 6 6 4 7 . But we can see that statistically it is a strange result, it is the only one so high with those values of a,b,c,d, so it is very unlikely that we're going to get, in the future, a high value choosing those values for a,b,c,d. Instead, seems much more safe to choose numbers that have generated "value" between 8 and 11. Although a 8 to 11 gain is less than 25.9, the probability that the values of a,b,c,d (5,2,3,3) generate this higher "value" is bigger

**Edit 3:** Although a,b,c,d are discrete, the combination/order of them will generate different results. I mean, there is a function that will return a value inside a small range, like: value=func(a,b,c,d). That value will depend not only on the values of a,b,c,d, but also on some random things. So, for instance, func(5,2,3,5) could return a value of 11.34, but it also could return a similar value, like 10.8, 9.5 or something like that (a range value between 8 and 11). Also, func(1,6,9,7) will return 0.23, or it could return 2.7, but probably it won't return 10.1 as it is also very far from its range.

Following the the example, I'm trying to get the numbers that most probably will generate something in the range of 8-11 (well, the maximum). Probably the numbers I want to visualize somehow will be some kind of combination of numbers 3,5 and 2. But probably there won't be any 6,7,4 numbers, as they usually generate smaller "value" results

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any statistics involved here. You can plot the value as a function of a and b.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A,B = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : A.flatten(), "b" : B.flatten(), 
                   "value" : np.random.rand(100)})

ax = df.plot.scatter(x="a",y="b", c=df["value"])

plt.colorbar(ax.collections[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The darker the dots, the higher the value.

Comment: Maybe `df.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b', c='value', s=df['value']*200)`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is absolutely bounded to two parameters. I mean, my bad, I know that I asked only about "a" and "b", but actually it would be much more useful to be able to do it with n variables (a, b, c, d, e...). I'm updating the question as probably it is better than create a new one.

Comment: What would be the information you are trying to gain from the plot then? (If you try to be explicit, it would sure help, like what could a,b,c, be and what would I know about them after having looked at the plot?)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the information I'm trying to get is: what values of a, b,c, d.. are statistically more likely to generate (thanks to some calculations) higher results in the "value" column.

Comment: So, one example: lets say that I have some specific values in a, b, c, d that I know that generate the highest value in "value". But may be that those values appears very few times, so statistically it is very difficult to get that higher result. Instead, would be better to get values for a,b,c,d that usually generates high results in "value", although the result probably is not the highest possible. I've added a new dataframe in the question trying to explain this

Comment: Your a,b,c,d are completely discrete. So I'm completely lost on what kind of statistics you want to do here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , I added some clarification about the question in edit3.

Comment: The mathematical description of the problem is still not clear to me. It seems to be rather a maths problem than a programming problem. Or maybe you just want to sort the list by value and select the n topmost combinations?

Comment: Is `f(3,2,1) == f(1,2,3) == f(2,3,1) == f(3,1,2) == f(1,3,2) == f(2,1,3)`?

Comment: That's exactly the problem; I want to sort by value and then select and visualize the top n parameters.But keeping in mind that some values, although could be very high, if they appear just once is because it is not a statistically good result. Also, the order of numbers matters for the final result, so f(3,2,1) != f(1,2,3) != f(2,3,1). But the result will be similar for each parameter, so: f(3,5,2) ~= f(4,5,2) ~= f(2,5,2) and probably !~f(8,7,9)

Comment: I was under the impression that every combiniation a,b,c,d, appears just once. It's getting more and more abstruse.

Comment: Using your plot code and two variables, the result I'm looking for is: Let's imagine that in your graphic there is one point, (1,2) for instance, with dark_value=1, darker than the other points, . All of the other points are not so dark, but this point is isolated in the visualization, in the bottom-left part. Then, in the upper-right part of the graphic, there are a bunch of points with a dark_value=0.9. They are not as dark as the darkest point, but probably, if I use values of (8,9), or (9,7), or (9,9), or (8,8), I'll get a high dark_value

Comment: Your visualization was actually perfect, the problem is that it only works for 2-variable as it uses 2 axes, one for x and the other for y

Comment: Cotinuing with the example in your graphic, if I use instead (1,1) or (2,2) I won't get a high dark_value

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be very complicated to solve it by one built-in function.

I think it should be solved in this way:

1. exclude outliers from data
2. select n largest values
3. summarize results with bar plot or any other

#### Clean data from outliers

We might choose any appropriate method for outliers detection e.g. 3*sigma, 1.5*IQR etc. I used 1.5*IQR in the example bellow.

```
cleaned_data = data[data['value'] < 1.5 * stats.iqr(data['value'])]
```

#### Select n largest values

*Pandas* provides method *nlargest*, so you can use it to select n largest values:

```
largest_values = cleaned_data.nlargest(5, 'value')
```

or you can use interval of values

```
largest_values = cleaned_data[cleaned_data['value'] > cleaned_data['value'].max() - 3]
```

#### Summarize results

Here we should count ocurrences of values in each column and then plot this data.

```
melted = pd.melt(largest_values['here you should select columns with explanatory variables'])
table = pd.crosstab(melted['variable'], melted['value'])
table.plot.bar()
```

[example of resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRkrl.png)